# Unique "traditional" souvenirs people may obtain from the pope or other Catholic prelates?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, resource-request, rome

**Unique "traditional" souvenirs people may obtain from the pope or other Catholic prelates?**

Believe it or not, there’s a way to get the pope to surrender his zucchetto to you, while in the presence of a pope while at Rome (papal audiences) or when he is on an apostolic visitation outside of Rome or Italy. All you have to do is offer him another one in exchange and you obtain an unique souvenir that was really worn by a pope.

It’s all part of an unique yet long-standing tradition among popes. And for the record, I am not talking about the large, ornate headwear called a [mitre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitre) you see the pope donning at a Papal Mass. I am talking about the white [zucchetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zucchetto) (skullcap). Just be warned: Few people have managed to pull off a successful trade with Francis so far.

> The process works like this: First, you have to acquire a zucchetto to trade with the pope. To do that, swing by [his tailor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammarelli) in Rome and purchase one for about $68. The tricky part here is trying to guess what size will fit Francis’ head best.
>
> Once you have your brand new zucchetto, the next challenge is actually finding the pope. Fortunately, Francis is known to give plenty of public appearances and has a history of mingling with the crowd in ways that [make his security staff uncomfortable](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/the-pope/11347984/Pope-Franciss-advisers-fear-for-his-security-in-Philippines.html). This should give you the perfect chance to weave through the faithful and get nice and close. - [Inside the wild and wacky tradition of the Papal hat trade](https://www.theloop.ca/inside-the-wild-and-wacky-tradition-of-the-papal-hat-trade/)

Here are a few successful zucchetto swaps:

- [Swapping Zucchettos with Pope Francis](https://cuaadmissions.wordpress.com/2017/04/05/swapping-zucchttos-with-pope-francis/)
- [Zucchetto swap with Pope Francis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT5yCqX2YNs)

**Question**: Do any similar, yet traditional ways of obtaining such unique souvenirs (non-zucchetto) from the pope or other high ranking Vatican officials exist while in their presence and while in Rome?

I have never heard of any other tradition existing or have found on the web. I hope someone here has some information on other unique papal or Roman traditions on how to obtain some religious item from a pope or cardinal.